# Can someone explain what the exchange lemma in the following context is trying to say?

Tags: linear-algebra

Exchange lemma:

Let V be a vector space over F and let $v_1, v_2,...., v_n \in V$. If
$$w \in span({v_1,v_2,..,v_n}) -  span({v_2,....,v_n})$$
then,  $$v_1 \in span({w,v_2,....,v_n}) - span({v_2,.....,v_n})$$

I have seen this lemma described in different ways, but I don't understand it as stated above. What does the author mean with the subtraction operation?. Is he thinking about a set operation? or is he thinking of a cross operation with subtraction?

Comment: This is the so-called "set difference" defined as follows: if $A$ and $B$ are sets, then $A \setminus B := \{x \mid x \in A \, \text{and} \, x \notin B\}$.

Comment: If $w$ can be written as a linear combination of $v_1,v_2,\dots,v_n$ but is unable to be written in such a way using only a linear combination of $v_2,\dots,v_n$, then it follows that $v_1$ can be written as a linear combination of $w,v_2,\dots,v_n$ but cannot be written as a linear combination using only $v_2,\dots,v_n$.

Answer (score 0):

I think the idea here is that any
[equivalence relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_relation)
on a set partitions that set into disjoint equivalence classes.
In the context of your question, we are given that
$\, A := \{v_2,\dots,v_n\}, \,$ 
 a set of vectors in $\ V. \,$ 
The equivalence relation is given by
 $\, x \sim y \iff x\in \textrm{span}(y,A). \,$
Check that it satisfies the three properties of an equivalence relation
and that $\, \textrm{span}(A) \,$ is an equivalence class.
What about other equivalence classes? If
 $\, w \sim v_1 \,$ and $\, w \notin \textrm{span}(A) \,$
then by the symmetry property of $\, \sim \,$ we know that
 $\, v_1 \sim w. \,$ Since equivalence classes are disjoint,
we know that $\, v_1 \notin \textrm{span}(A) \,$ also. That is exactly what the exchange lemma is stating.